# How to map separated column-values into one new column?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame column in this form (semicolon-separated):

`colOld <- data.frame(Farbtemperatur = c("3450K; 4100K", "6400K", ""))`

I want to map that values to a new column by this conditions:

```
mapFarbtemp <- function(farbtemperatur) {
      if(farbtemperatur > 2500 & farbtemperatur < 3500) return("Warmweiß")
      if(farbtemperatur > 3500 & farbtemperatur < 5300) return("Neutralweiß")
      if(farbtemperatur > 5300) return("Kaltweiß")
    }
```

to get the following:

```
colNew <- data.frame(Farbtemperatur = c("Warmweiß; Neutralweiß", "Kaltweiß", ""))
```

I tried to use `mutate()` and `sapply()` but get the following warning:

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What could a solution look like?

Comment: You have to present a minimal dataset with ~ 10 rows and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `case_when()` function for this from the `dplyr` package.

```r
colOld <- data.frame(Farbtemperatur = c("3450K", "4100K", "6400", ""))
library(dplyr)
colOld %>% 
  mutate(colNew = case_when(Farbtemperatur  > 2500 & Farbtemperatur < 3500 ~ "Warmweiß",
                            Farbtemperatur > 3500 & Farbtemperatur < 5300 ~ "Neutralweiß",
                            Farbtemperatur > 5300 ~ "Kaltweiß"))
```

Above I worked with the assumption that the data was not correctly inputted.

If your data really looks like this, you'd have to do some data wrangling first - my suggestion would be to use the `separate()` function and then collect all different columns with the `pivot_longer` command:

```r
colOld <- data.frame(Farbtemperatur = c("3450K; 4100K", "6400", ""))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

colOld %>% 
  separate(Farbtemperatur, sep = ";", into = c("startvalue", "endvalue"), fill = "right", remove = FALSE)  %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Farbtemperatur,values_to = "values") %>% 
  mutate(values = as.numeric(gsub("K","",values))) %>% 
  mutate(Farbtemperatur_new = case_when(values  > 2500 & values < 3500 ~ "Warmweiß",
                                        values > 3500 & values < 5300 ~ "Neutralweiß",
                                        values > 5300 ~ "Kaltweiß")) %>% 
  select(-values) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = Farbtemperatur_new) %>% 
  mutate(Farbtemperatur_final = paste0(startvalue,";",endvalue)) %>% 
  select(Farbtemperatur, Farbtemperatur_final)
```

Now the result looks like this:

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Farbtemperatur Farbtemperatur_final
  <chr>          <chr>               
1 "3450K; 4100K" Warmweiß;Neutralweiß
2 "6400"         Kaltweiß;NA         
3 ""             NA;NA
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but that would only work, if each row has in this column one Value (not ";"-separated)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i need the "new Values" in the same way like the input, that means:

"3100K;3900K" --> "Warmweiß; Neutralweiß"

Comment: Edited again - is this what you're looking for? 
Note that the input data above is not consistent, which makes this a bit tedious. The 3450 and 4100 have a K, the 6400 does not - and the 6400 is separated by a comma with the empty string (rather than a semi-colon). All of the above works with this data, but thought you might want to double check :)

Answer (score 0):

```r
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, assertthat)

colOld <- data.frame(Farbtemperatur = c("3450K; 4100K", "6400", ""))
colOld
#>   Farbtemperatur
#> 1   3450K; 4100K
#> 2           6400
#> 3

mapFarbtemp <- function(farbtemperatur) {
  farbtemperatur <- farbtemperatur %>% 
    str_extract("\\d+") %>%
    as.numeric()
  case_when(
    farbtemperatur > 2500 & farbtemperatur < 3500 ~ "Warmweiß",
    farbtemperatur >= 3500 & farbtemperatur < 5300 ~ "Neutralweiß",
    farbtemperatur >= 5300 ~ "Kaltweiß",
    TRUE ~ ""
  )
}

assertthat::are_equal(mapFarbtemp("3500K"), "Neutralweiß")
#> [1] TRUE
assertthat::are_equal(mapFarbtemp("6400"), "Kaltweiß")
#> [1] TRUE
assertthat::are_equal(mapFarbtemp(" 4100K"), "Neutralweiß")
#> [1] TRUE

colOld %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Farbtemperatur2 = Farbtemperatur %>%
           str_split(";") %>%
           map(mapFarbtemp) %>%
           unlist() %>%
           unique() %>%
           str_c(collapse = "; ")) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Farbtemperatur Farbtemperatur2        
#>   <chr>          <chr>                  
#> 1 "3450K; 4100K" "Warmweiß; Neutralweiß"
#> 2 "6400"         "Kaltweiß"             
#> 3 ""             ""
```

Comment: Hey, your script is running well.

Just only small thing: How can i prevent to list the same values multiple times?
Maybe thats enough?
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(Lichtfarbe = Farbtemperatur %>%
               str_split(";") %>%
               map(mapFarbtemp) %>%
               unlist() %>%
               unique() %>% 
               str_c(collapse = "; ")) %>%
      ungroup()

Comment: Exactly. You just need to add `unique()`.